# Angular Universal platform server Initially does not show some component css styles

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Some component styles in my angular universal app do not work until the app completely loads.

Below you can see that the html coming from *AppServerModuleNgFactory* will not be linked to its css cause the HTML is does not include the same pattern as everywhere else (`serverApp`)

How can I get the html coming from the server to be `_ngcontent-serverApp-...` instead of `_ngcontent-s` like the css expects???

---

**The render that is sent from server.ts (AppServerModuleNgFactory)**

*css:* `.copy[_ngcontent-serverApp-c16]`

*html:* `<div _ngcontent-sc16="" class="copy">`

**After app loads (preboot complete)**

*css:* `.copy[_ngcontent-serverApp-c16]`

*html:* `<div _ngcontent-serverapp-c16="" class="copy">`

---

The only mention of `serverApp` was in **app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    PrebootModule.withConfig({ appRoot: 'app-root' }),
    ...
]
```

#### browser.d.ts

```
export declare class BrowserModule {
    constructor(parentModule: BrowserModule | null);
    /**
     * Configures a browser-based app to transition from a server-rendered app, if
     * one is present on the page.
     *
     * @param params An object containing an identifier for the app to transition.
     * The ID must match between the client and server versions of the app.
     * @returns The reconfigured `BrowserModule` to import into the app's root `AppModule`.
     */
    static withServerTransition(params: {
        appId: string;
    }): ModuleWithProviders<BrowserModule>;
}
```

I think this file's comments tell me exactly what is wrong but i dont know what to do with this info. *The ID must match between the client and server versions of the app.*

Comment: The above given code doesn't help at all. The _ngcontent-serverApp-c16 is an auto generated name Convention.

Comment: Please share which how are you bindling these css files. Or which components are these ? Also angular version ? from angular 9 onwards, SSR has become a lot simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's safe to use the attributes angular generates, use only .copy class. If you need more specific rule you can get it from your html:

```
CSS: .copy{}    
HTML: <div class="copy"></div>
        
CSS: .copy{}    
CSS: .copy2{} // will be triggered only if condition is true
HTML: <div class="copy" [class.copy2]="condition"></div>
```